# CakePHP - SUM data in another relation Table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have no idea in getting a result for sum of hours that staff has been attend to courses and assembly. Here are my database:-

```
staffs
+---+-------+-----------+
| id| Name  | Department|
+---+-------+-----------+
| 1 | Joe   | HR        |
| 2 | Andra | Support   |
| 3 | Khan  | HR        |
| 4 | Toll  | HR        |
| 5 | Gosh  | Support   |
| 6 | Rama  | Support   |
+---+-------+-----------+



attendances
+---+---------+-----------+--------------+
|id | name_id | course_id | assembly_id  |
+---+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 1 |    1    |  101      |              |
| 2 |    1    |  102      |              |
| 3 |    1    |           | 501          |
| 4 |    2    |  102      |              |
| 5 |    3    |           | 502          |
| 6 |    3    |  103      |              |
| 7 |    4    |  101      |              |
| 8 |    4    |           | 501          |
| 9 |    4    |  102      |              |
+---+---------+-----------+--------------+    


courses
+-------+-----------+-------+
| id    | name      | hours |
+-------+-----------+-------+
| 101   | courses_1 | 8     |
| 102   | courses_2 | 6     |
| 103   | courses_3 | 9     |
+-------+-----------+-------+


assembly
+-------+---------------+-------+
| id    | name          | hours |
+-------+---------------+-------+
| 501   | assembly_1    | 2     |
| 502   | assembly_2    | 4     |
+-------+---------------+-------+
```

In Model > Attendance i already add a relation:-

```
public $belongsTo = array('Staff','Course','Assembly');
```

In my Controller i try write this code:-

```
$view = $this->Staff->find('all',array(
'fields' => array('SUM(COALESCE(Course.hours,0))+SUM(COALESCE(Assembly.hours,0)) as ec_count'),'recursive'=>2));
$this->set('view', $view);
```

But it will return an errors..(Seem like i do some wrong here)

How to write a codes with this condition and it will appears through a view like this:-

```
+---+-------+-----------+------------+
| id| Name  | Attend    | Total Hour |
+---+-------+-----------+------------+
| 1 | Joe   | course_1  |      16    |
|   |       | course_2  |            |
|   |       | assembly_1|            |
| 2 | Andra | course_2  |       6    |
| 3 | Khan  | assembly_2|      13    |
|   |       | course_3  |            |
| 4 | Khan  | course_1  |      16    |
|   |       | assembly_1|            |
|   |       | course_2  |            |
| 5 | Gosh  | -         |      0     |
| 6 | Rama  | -         |      0     |
+---+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: are you using cake2.x? try to use virtual fields here instead of mixing fields and custom sql. it is cleaner to read/understand and it will be cleaner to work with.

Comment: i am using cake2..but newer try virtual fields..like to find an easier guide in understanding using Virtual Fields @mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're doing Joins (see [CakePHP Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)), you will not be able to get the SUMs like that, as CakePHP will actually run individual queries, then combine and return the data.

I think you're best bet would be to keep track of the total hours in `Staff.course_hours` and `Staff.assembly_hours` fields within the 'staffs' table.  You can still keep the individual rows in the `Assembly.hours` and `Course.hours`, but then on an `afterSave()` (see CakePHP [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave)) callback (or something similar), update the Staff hours fields.

Then, you can just set up a virtual field (see [CakePHP Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)) called `total_hours` that you can sort by, or display, or use for anything you need.

OR, you could just build out the Joins and do it in a single (though slightly more complex) query.

Comment: Thanks for advice, i would like to try keep track of total in my staff table first.